# How to setup logic for retrofit to skip loading if the request returns 404?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-glide

I'm new to Android development.

My app is using Hearthstone API. Hearthstone is an online card playing game.

The API will return a URL for the image of a card along with other Strings of information such as card name and card information.

unfortunately the API will return a URL that reaches 404 so an image is never displayed.

If interested here is the GIT with my code
https://github.com/KaasiSerrano/HearthstoneAPI

I would like to implement logic that will skip loading anything that doesn't return a proper card image URL.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVbSe.jpg

I'm looking for something like this

```
if(url == [404])
{
   skip loading this card and skip to the next card to check if that one has a proper URL or not
}
```

This is my Retrofit request. I think this is where my logic should be but i'm not sure.

```
public void retrofitRequest() {

            HearthstoneService hearthstoneService =
                    RetrofitClientInstance
                            .getRetrofit()
                            .create(HearthstoneService.class);


 Call<List<Cards>> call = hearthstoneService.loadSetCards(ThisIsSetName);


            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cards>>() {
                @Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Cards>>call,Response<List<Cards>> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        assert response.body() != null;

                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse" + response.body());


                        cardAdapter.setData(response.body());
                        rvCards.setAdapter(cardAdapter);


                    } else {
                        assert response.errorBody() != null;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponseError" + response.errorBody().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(DisplaySetCards.this, "Card Doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Cards>> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });

        }
```

I'm using Glide to load these images but I think that the code i'm looking for should happen before i'm loading the images? I'm not sure.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVbSe.jpg

```
 Glide.with(context).load(urlGolden).placeholder(R.drawable.error404card).into(holder.iv_Card_Image);
```

The output should only be cards with an actual URL card.

Comment: I dont think this logic should be in retrofit. Since retrofit job is to get the response from the api and this is something that is inside the api's response. This logic should be implemented while you are loading the image. i.e in Glide

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Attach a image loading listener to glide and if an exceptions occurs remove that item from the list.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.color.Black)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
            .dontAnimate()
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                   // HERE remove that item from the list

                    Log.d(TAG,e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
```